# Spring-Boot Cannot Add Google Guava Dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, guava

I want to add Guava collections into my application but I couldn't be successful. Here is my pom definition:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I want to use  `MultiMap` but it cannot see Guava dependencies. On the other hand my IDE suggests me `org.jvnet.hk2.component` inside Glassfish. However I don't use Glassfish.

How can I add Guava dependency and remove that Glassfish dependency?

Comment: Open your pom.xml (in Eclipse IDE), select `dependency Hierarchy` tab, search for `org.jvnet.hk2` dependecy and exclude it. Try to put specific version of guava and choose `maven - update`.

Comment: Actually I don't wanna break any compatibility.

Comment: Can you add an error message to the question? Make sure you use `Multimap` and not `MultiMap`, which is not a Guava class.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add spring-context-support as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding spring-context-support resolved the issue. I wonder what happens underneath. Why we do need an extra dependency to tell the IDE to use original guava? What is spring-context-support?

Comment: No where else is mentioned to add spring-context-support while using spring. This answer is savior.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like version compatibility issues.

Guava default comes with spring boot server , if you need a specific version you have to override the default with specific version.

Comment: Adding `<version>19.0</version>` does not solves my problem too.

Comment: I have upgraded from 2.2.0 to 2.7.8, and seems like is not included anymore, getting errors about missing package com.google.common.*